# Changing css to a tag depending of the content inside it

Tags: python, html, css, django

I would like to know if there is a way in which using css i would be able to change the css properties, i was thinking if there is any way such as when working with input types, you indicate input[type='submit'] for example, and set your css for that specifical input, or the correct way of doing it.

## HTML

```
  <td><div class="perform"><a href="{%url 'appointmentupdate' consult.id %}">{%if consult.Medicamento%}Modificar{%else%}Realizar{%endif%}</a></div></td>
```

This is the tag i want to apply this on. I would like to set some border above with some color, but specific for each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No exist any CSS selector to individual words, but you could wrap each word inside a `span` element with a CSS `class` (id or inline style) and give style individually. For example:

```
.a {
color: red;
}
.b {
color: red;
}

<span class="a">Hello</span> <span class="a">World</span>
```

This is a pure CSS solution but if you have a text with too many words probably a solution using JavaScript or a heavy logic in your templates will be needed

Comment: Thank you! @Yasiel Cabrera, that was the solution i find out earlier! Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to check the value of that tag and change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 ways to specify attributes for HTML tags in css first of them is to using tag name for example `span {color:red;}` second is to using a class name of your tags for example when your HTML is like this `<span class='first-span'>` then you can specify attributes for this tag like this `.first-span{color:red;}` you can have more that one tag with a same class name... third is to using Id of your tags when your HTML be like this `<span id='first-span;>` your css should be like this `#first-span{color:red;}`